# trying to run .sql file through powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlite, terminal, echo

hello I am trying to run .sql file through my ex0.db and also I’m adding the sqlite3 -echo so I can see what statements run and what they produce. But it keeps giving me this error...

command: sqlite3 -echo -init ex7.sql ex0.db

PS C:\Users\sasaz\sqlite_driver\sql_exes> sqlite3 -init -echo ex7.sql ex0.db
cannot open: "-echo"
Error: in prepare, near "ex0": syntax error
ex0.db
^--- error here

but in a book i am learning from this command work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You've added the `-echo` in the wrong place by mistake in the example that's giving an error.

Correct command:

```
sqlite3 -echo -init ex7.sql ex0.db
```

Which [according to the manual](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#command_line_options) will be read as these arguments:

- `-echo` - print commands before execution
- `-init ex7.sql` - read/process the file "ex7.sql"
- `ex0.db` - the name of an SQLite database

Incorrect command:

```
sqlite3 -init -echo ex7.sql ex0.db
```

Which is read as:

- `-init -echo` - read/process the file "-echo"
- `ex7.sql` - the name of an SQLite database
- `ex0.db` - SQL to execute

Comment: PS C:\Users\Pajder\lsthw\sql> sqlite3 -echo -init ex7.sql ex5.db
-- Loading resources from ex7.sql

So now it runs without error but -echo is not working...
but when i am in sqlite and use insert for example it repeats my command like this --
--> 
sqlite> insert into pet values (4, 'vendulka_2', 'village_dog', 15, 1);

insert into pet values (4, 'vendulka_2', 'village_dog', 15, 1);

but when running from file it doesn't print anything